# AS3 Security Sandbox Error when retrieving data from Facebook

Tags: actionscript-3, security, facebook-graph-api

I think this is a common problem, but can't find the answer.

I've got a Flash app that's trying to retrieve data, whenever it attempts to access the data from Facebook I get

*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'http://example.com/page.html' tried to access incompatible context 'http://cdn.example.com/flashfile.swf'

This error doesn't happen any other time, only from when I try and access data from Facebook.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [allowDomain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#allowDomain%28%29)?

```
import flash.system.Security;
...
Security.allowDomain("facebook.com");
```